# Unable to center two columns next to eachother with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm working on a profile website and it's overall been progessing quite nicely.

I've been working on making it more responsive today, but since after having implementing bootstrap on a carousel object its navigatinoal buttons are messed up and I can't figure out how to set them up correctly.

This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Todai/pen/grKvjO). What I need is for the buttons to be centered next to eachother and below the carousel...

Here is the snippet where I set the button's divs up:

```
                     </div> //closes the previous row


                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-4 col-offset-xs-1">
                            <div class="prev">Prev</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-4 ">
                            <div class="next">Next</div>
                          </div>
                       </div> 

               </div> // closes the wrapping container
```

Comment: The code snippet above is not formatted so as to be easily readable and it contains extra code unrelated to demonstrating your button positioning issue.  Furthermore, the snippet looks nothing at all like what you have implemented in the codepen you have linked.  Your codepen has the "Prev" button located above the carousel in the markup and the "Next" button located below the carousel in the markup...  you will never get them centered below the carousel in any sane manner without moving them both below the carousel in the markup.

Comment: The pen seems to "work", in that the buttons appear positioned correctly. Also, the pen doesn't seem to match the code posted here.

Comment: I've edited the snippet so that it is more readable.
I'm not sure about what you guys are saying about the pen. The buttons do not have the positioning that I want them to have (beneath the carousel, next to each other and centered in the section).
The snippet is exactly as it is in the codepen that i linked...